# D3js: Unable to rotate axis labels

Tags: html, css, d3.js

My d3js barplot has long axis labels and they are overlapping. I've been trying to rotate the labels but every time I try, the labels disappear. This is my code:

```js
// create 3 data_set
var republic= [
    {group: "IndiaWithArnab", value: 52},
     {group: "RepublicFightsBack", value: 46},
     {group: "CBIForSSR", value: 42},
     {group: "KanganaSpeaksToArnab", value: 12},
     {group: "BharatForKangana", value: 11},
     {group: "SoniaGoonsAttackArnab", value: 11},
     {group: "ReportForSSR", value: 10},
     {group: "RepublicExposesParamBir", value: 10}
 
 ];
 
 var ndtv= [
      {group: "BTSOnNDTV", value: 18},
     {group: "coronavirus", value: 11},
     {group: "BTS", value: 9},
     {group: "ProtestAgainstExamslnCOVID", value: 9},
     {group: "RavishKumar", value: 9},
     {group: "CoronavirusLockdown", value: 6},
     {group: "Hathras", value: 6},
     {group: "KanganaRanaut", value: 6}
 
 ];
 
 var cnn = [
     {group: "NewsAlert", value: 5},
     {group: "CaughtOnCam", value: 5},
     {group: "IndiaFightsCOVID19", value: 2},
     {group: "RajasthanPoliticalCrisis", value: 2},
     {group: "WATCH", value: 1},
  ];
 
 
var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60},
width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#hashtags")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Initialize the X axis
var x = d3.scaleBand()
.range([ 0, width ])
.padding(0.2);
var xAxis = svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")



var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([ height, 0]);
var yAxis = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "myYaxis")


// A function that create / update the plot for a given variable:
function update(data) {

// Update the X axis
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.group; }))
xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x))

// Update the Y axis
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value }) ]);
yAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisLeft(y));

var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)

u
.enter()
.append("rect") // Add a new rect for each new elements
.merge(u) // get the already existing elements as well
.transition() // and apply changes to all of them
.duration(1000)
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.group); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
  .attr("fill", "#A6ACC9")

// If less group in the new dataset, I delete the ones not in use anymore
u
.exit()
.remove()
}

// Initialize the plot with the first dataset
update(republic)
```

This gives me a decent graph [shown here](https://ibb.co/LxfZzCk), but as you can see the labels are overlapping. I tried adding the following lines to the place where I am initializing the X axis:

```js
 // Initialize the X axis
 var x = d3.scaleBand()
   .range([ 0, width ])
   .padding(0.2);
 var xAxis = svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
   .selectAll("text")
     .attr("fill", "#A6ACC9")
     .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)rotate(-45)")
     .attr("font-style", "cocogoose")
     .attr("font-size", "15px");
```

[image]

The labels have disappeared, along with the axis. What am I doing wrong and how can I rotate these labels?

Edit: [My codesandbox is available here](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-playground-forked-807mp?file=/public/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apply the x-axis label transform code to the x-axis.

```
xAxis
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("fill", "#A6ACC9")
    .attr("font-style", "cocogoose")
    .attr("font-size", "8px")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-45) translate(-50,0)");
```

Codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-playground-forked-trwoj?file=/public/charts.js:1952-2161

[image: with rotated axes]